# Join on output result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How come this query fails to run?

```
select * 
from ass 
join (
    UPDATE [dsa]
    SET col1='123'
    OUTPUT inserted.*) as ds on ass.dsaid = ds.ID
```

Comment: what do want to do? INSERT or UPDATE?

Comment: Why not you first update, than make a select join..

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, please post the **exact** and **complete** error message - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it in two steps.  Use your `OUTPUT` clause to go to a variable, then select from that variable:

```
DECLARE @tbl_out TABLE(ID int, col VARCHAR(10));

UPDATE [dsa] SET [col1] = '123'
OUTPUT inserted.* INTO @tbl_out

SELECT * FROM ass JOIN @tbl_out ds ON ass.dsaid = ds.ID
```

(not tested)